# Drupal Views using over ride feature with civicrm fields - token

Tags: drupal, civireport, drupal-views, tokens

I am wonder whether someone can help explain how to use the Override feature for CiviCRM fields in views.  For example, I have a field in Civi which is a file field... when i add it to a view it shows the URL to the image... I assume I can select the field in question and then when it opens the configuration window for the field:

[image]

Select over ride and in the text area write something like

```
 <img src=['token for the field']>
```

for it to render the image is this correct and if it is how would i workout what needs to be placed in the ['token for the field'] portion of the string?

Answer (score 1):

Ok have worked this one out... was very much a "DOH!" moment... there is a section called Replacement Patterns under the ReWrite section - which is collapsed by default and can be overlooked which had the taken information.